# How may I resolve "Tree not correctly binarized" error in StanfordCoreNLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

**I'm getting an error when run stanfordCoreNLP to get sentiment as below: I'm on version 4.0.0 currently, would you pls advise?**

SentimentCostAndGradient: warning: Tree not correctly binarized: (ROOT (: --) (S (VB let) (SBARQ (NP 's) (@SBARQ (ADVP just) (@SBARQ (VBP say) (SQ (S (VBG assuming) (SBAR (NP you) (VP (@VP (@VP (VBP get) (NP (JJ supportive) (NN legislation))) (NP (DT this) (NN year))) (PP (IN in) (NP (DT the) (@NP (NNP Texas) (NN legislature))))))) (@SQ (, ,) (@SQ (SBARQ (WHNP what) (SQ (VBZ 's) (NP (NP (DT the) (@NP (NN time) (NN line))) (PP (IN to) (S (VBG getting) (S (NP (DT an) (@NP (NNP AMI) (NN program))) (VP deployed))))))) (@SQ (, ,) (@SQ (@SQ (MD shall) (NP we)) (VP (@VP (@VP (@VP (VB say) (, ,)) (INTJ right)) (, ,)) (S (ADVP so) (VP (@VP (@VP (VBG starting) (PP (IN from) (NP midyear))) (NP (DT this) (NN year))) (ADVP onwards))))))))))))) (. ?))
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Tree not correctly binarized
at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCostAndGradient.forwardPropagateTree(SentimentCostAndGradient.java:532)
at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCostAndGradient.forwardPropagateTree(SentimentCostAndGradient.java:512)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentimentAnnotator.doOneSentence(SentimentAnnotator.java:115)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentenceAnnotator.annotate(SentenceAnnotator.java:102)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:76)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:640)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:650)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1245)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1079)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.run(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1362)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1408)

**The text I input to StanfordCoreNLP module:**

Can you hear me? So a few follow-up questions if you can. First, let me just hit some of the details here on the credit side and the equity raise. Just how do you think about your [sort of] debt metrics, where they are today? Obviously, there's been some commentary already from the agencies. But -- and where do you need to go? I know you said you're not going to be specific today about the total quantum of equity needed, but just want to make sure we understand where you are today and where you need to go from a credit perspective. And I'm assuming that you want to sustain your current respective ratings. Got it, okay. And then let me come back to this twist, as far as I perceive it, with respect to the 50 to 150 megawatts -- or rather the upside outside of the procurement rather, is maybe the better way to say this, right? So you ran the RFP. You announced those results already. But then in the slides here, you talk about purchasing, it seems like, an additional quantum, if I -- if you will. Can you talk about that a little bit? And then just to be clear here, obviously, you awarded -- or you are proposing to award PPAs here. Would this be a potential build-own-transfer situation? And actually maybe even -- let me broaden this out, is the initially awarded RFP capacity potentially a build-own-transfer situation at all? And what's the time line for that, just if you don't mind reminding me? Just in terms of those -- I know you have this little description broadly this year about when you're getting these contracts done. But the time line specifically around the build-own-transfer, BOT, piece of that maybe. Got it, excellent. And then sorry, one last one just with respect to the AMI effort. The time line there, how are you thinking about -- let's just say assuming you get supportive legislation this year in the Texas legislature, what's the time line to getting an AMI program deployed, shall we say, right, so starting from midyear this year onwards? In the 2019 guidance, what level of rate relief is assumed with regards to both the -- and with regards to Texas as well, both the transmission as well as the distribution? Okay. Because looks like based on the way you file these things, it would seem like the transmission one should be available for the summer peak, while the distribution increase may not be there for the summer peak. No, I certainly appreciate that and understand that. But out of the $16 million request, under the assumption that those dollars in aggregate are approved, based on the time line, how much realistically falls into '19 versus '20? Okay. Also, in terms of equity, what is the -- in terms of your guidance, what's the share count assumption in terms of incremental equity for your 2019 guidance? Also, you've filed and -- waiting on the request for the approval. It was up to $200 million. I guess, can you help us in terms of -- timing-wise in terms of how the -- over what years or how you're thinking about that? Does that flexibility also contemplate the ability for funding the equity if you're able to reach an agreement with some of the RFP winners to build to buy, like Julien was describing? Can you give us a little bit of color on what you've seen in first quarter weather so far? Okay. And can you give us any sense of what you've seen out of the Texas legislature so far in terms of AMI? Okay. And as far as -- you gave us some idea of what the DCRF might look like this year. Are those numbers, you think, sort of what baseline annual numbers might look like? Or are you that far behind that these might be a little bit above normal sort of going forward? So maybe like half? Assuming your customer and load growth continues at similar rates, that -- that would maybe suggest about half would be what the going-forward rate might be. Yes. My understanding is that there's an effort in the -- with the legislature to empower the PUCT to be able to use forecasted test years for rate cases to help mitigate regulatory lag. I'm simply wondering kind of what you're -- what you're aware about that effort and the status and what you think the prospects are. Yes. I think I was kind of referring in -- to generation rider, probably more in a broader context. But did you -- if it's right now focused particularly on a generation rider, I guess what do you -- how do you see that right now? Sorry, guys, to follow up here. But I just wanted to clarify this, how do you think about your earned ROE baked into the '19 guidance here? Again, I know you talk about normalized weather, but I just want to understand earned ROE expectations and how those are established. And I'm really principally obviously asking more on the distribution side than the transmission side, if we can kind of dig into that. Got it. But the average reflected on the distribution side between the 2 jurisdictions is slightly below 9% on the distribution side.

Here is how I ran the model, I am on 4.1.0 version:

```
java -mx3g -cp "/home/cxiao/release_date/stanford-corenlp-4.1.0/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props.q1
```

For props.q1:

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, sentiment
outputFormat = JSON 
outputDirectory = /path_to/standard_input/fail/
timeout = 500000
output.includeText = False
parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
continueOnAnnotateError = True
filelist = /path_to/stanford-corenlp-4.1.0/q/flist1.lst
```

For filelist:

```
/pathto/failed_file.txt
```

Comment: Would you explain how you're running this?  If I put all the text into a file and run it like this, I don't get an error with the current CoreNLP: java edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse, sentiment" --file foo.txt

Comment: Note that he is using 4.1.0

Comment: @John  I've added how I was running to the bottom of my question. I was using 4.1.0 too but still, have the failure.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp I was using 4.1.0, still have the same error. Added the commands and property file I was using to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @John Hey! I noticed that if I remove the line parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz from the property file, the model actually works. But may I know why I can't use that parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really obscure bug in the sr parser, caused by a small handful of training trees in one of the recently added training sets breaking the assumption that all trees end with S, FRAG, etc and then go to ROOT as a unary transition.  The error produced here is only part of the sentence causing the problem, and the sr parser was trying to split that sentence into two pieces with two separate ROOTs.  In fact, the problem is even weirder than that, since this only caused a bug downstream when one of those ROOTs then had 3 or more pieces.

Anyway, the bug can be fixed by enforcing that ROOT nodes only occur at the very top of the tree.  That fix is in this branch of the source tree:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/fix_sr_binary

If you don't see a branch there, that means it's already been merged into

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/dev

The plan is to post a new release in the next few weeks, at which point you can simply use the new release rather than build from source in order to get this bugfix.

Edit: You specifically want this change

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/commit/10881ca4727b6d114e5157d2aa547bceac18d294

Anything past that will not be able to load old models, since there's a hack in readObject required to make it load the old models and we're going to redo the models with the updated transition rules